# Windows 10 "msiexec.exe" manifest still at 8.1

Tags: windows-installer

It appears that **Windows 10** Insider Preview ships an `msiexec.exe` that contains an manifest with "supportedOS" = 8.1. This breaks detection of some Windows 10 elements, like `VersionNT`, DirectX, IIS, etc.

Can anyone confirm if this is an known problem? Any ETA for a fix?

Comment: You may need to supply more detail. What vakue of VersionNT(64) do you get back? What do DirectX and IIS have to do with Windows Installer?  Occasionaly new versions of the OS ship with "wrong" values of VersionNT so that setups with risky launch conditions based on VersionNT can still install and apps tested, and exe and MSI files have a Compatibility tab in the properties to change some of that, or maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely.

Comment: VersionNT=603 (just like Win 8.1), but it should probably be 1000.

Comment: +1 This problem still exists in the released version of Windows 10 now, even with all the available windows updates installed.

Answer (score 0):

At this time its obvious that Microsoft is NOT going to fix it, quite the opposite: MSI technology is deprecated in Windows 10.

However, *Advanced Installer* computes correctly `VersionNT(64)=1000` on **Windows 10** and Windows Server 2016!

Answer (score 0):

Since the Windows Installer property VersionNT is giving a "wrong" value on Win 10 we're forced to find an alternate way of detecting the OS. I found that a very easy and robust way of detecting Windows 10 is by calling the built-in WMIC command and parsing the output from it:

```
wmic os get Name,Version,BuildNumber /VALUE
```

It'll return exactly the info you need to determine which OS you're on:

> BuildNumber=14393
>
> Version=10.0.**14393**

http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/whats_newIS2015.htm

> On systems with Windows 10, the Windows Installer properties VersionNT
> and VersionNT64 indicate 603, which was originally introduced as the
> version number of Windows 8.1. Therefore, it is not possible to create
> conditions in an .msi package that specifically target Windows 10.
>
> Since Windows Installer 5.0 and Windows 7, DLL custom actions in .msi
> packages are shimmed to block obtaining the operating system version;
> the APIs GetVersion, GetVersionEx, and RtlGetVersion return a Windows
> version of 6.0.6000, which was originally the version number of
> Windows Vista. Therefore, it is also not possible to obtain the actual
> version number of Windows from a DLL custom action or from an
> InstallScript custom action (which is implemented as a DLL).
>
> Because of the aforementioned behavior in Windows Installer, it is not
> easily possible to detect what version of Windows on which an .msi
> package is running